# Grails Spring Security Rest Basic Configuration

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am creating the backend in Grails that needs to support both mobile app & web app.
I have managed to use `compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'` for the authentication. It works fine.

Now I want to make it restful for the mobile app to call the api. So I added the following in the BuildConfig.groovy.

```
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.1", {
    excludes: 'spring-security-core'
}
```

I am following this tutorial to use `spring-security-rest`.
http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/tokenStorage.html

In my app, I have User domain which extends SecUser.

Here is my Config.grrovy.

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'm15.authentication.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'm15.authentication.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'm15.authentication.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]


grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active  = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = '401'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials  = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName =  'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName =  'password'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/api/logout'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom  = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID  = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName   = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'tokenValue'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName   = 'username'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.usernamePropertyName  = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.authoritiesPropertyName   = 'roles'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active   = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName   = 'X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.endpointUrl  = '/api/validate'

//Exclude normal controllers from basic auth filter. Just the JSON API is included
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

I'm not sure what to do next. How can I to call the api? For example, I have Client domain. How to get the list of all clients with the rest api?

Client.groovy

```
class Client {

    Long id
    String name

    String toString(){
        "${name}"
    }

    static hasMany = [users: User, apps: App]

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
    }
}
```

ClientController.groovy

```
package m15

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ClientController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Client.list(params), model:[clientInstanceCount: Client.count()]
    }

    def show(Client clientInstance) {
        respond clientInstance
    }

    def create() {
        respond new Client(params)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(Client clientInstance) {
        if (clientInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (clientInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond clientInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        clientInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'client.label', default: 'Client'), clientInstance.id])
                redirect clientInstance
            }
            '*' { respond clientInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(Client clientInstance) {
        respond clientInstance
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(Client clientInstance) {
        if (clientInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (clientInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond clientInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        clientInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Client.label', default: 'Client'), clientInstance.id])
                redirect clientInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond clientInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(Client clientInstance) {

        if (clientInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        clientInstance.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'Client.label', default: 'Client'), clientInstance.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'client.label', default: 'Client'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to login and get a token?

I am using Grails 3.2.0.M1 and the following settings in `application.groovy`
I setup a test app and use GORM to store tokens.

I first needed to install the gorm plugin otherwise the tokens would not get stored.

`compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:2.0.0.M2"`

application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl='/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode=401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName='password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl='/api/logout'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName='dashboard.AuthToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName='tokenValue'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.endpointUrl='/api/validate'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.expiration=99999
```

I used curl to test the login and see if a token was returned:

`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"me","password":"password"}' http://localhost:8090/api/login`

This returned:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8090 (#0)
> POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:8090
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 39
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 112
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 09:34:00 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"username":"me","roles":["ROLE_ADMIN"],"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"ek6bonq0jnvn40pbgb4qamptorfrdotb"}
```

The `access_token` is `ek6bonq0jnvn40pbgb4qamptorfrdotb`

Secured controller test action:

```
class TestController {

    def index() { 
        def l = SysRole.list()

        render l as JSON
    }
}
```

Then I tested this secured controller using curl and the token which lists the user roles:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8090/test -H "Authorization: Bearer ek6bonq0jnvn40pbgb4qamptorfrdotb"  


* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8090 (#0)
> POST /test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:8090
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ek6bonq0jnvn40pbgb4qamptorfrdotb
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Application-Context: application:development:8090
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 09:39:52 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":1,"authority":"ROLE_ADMIN"},{"id":2,"authority":"ROLE_USER"}]
```

Testing with an invalid token gives a 401 unauthorized:

```
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8090 (#0)
> POST /test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:8090
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer invalid_token
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 09:43:08 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```